# How can horizontal asymptote of $\frac{x^{}}{x^{2}+4}$ allow the origin to be plotted?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So, horizontal asymptote of this rational function $\frac{x^{}}{x^{2}+4}$  is y = 0.

But this function's graph goes through the origin which is (0, 0).

I don't understand this. If horizontal asymptote doesn't allow any y value to be 0, how can the origin be plotted, which has the y value of 0? Is there an exception for origin? I thought the graph was never supposed to cross the asymptotes.

Comment: consider the graph of $y = \frac{\sin x}x.$ this graph has the horizontal asymptote $y = 0.$ the graph crosses this infinitely many times!

Comment: @abel that is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual definition is something like this: If $f$ is a function defined for all real numbers, then a horizontal line $y = c$ is a *horizontal asymptote* of $f$ if
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = c\quad\text{and/or}\quad \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = c.
$$
It's a common misunderstanding that the graph of a function cannot cross a horizontal asymptote. For example, the function
$$
f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{1 + x^{2}}
$$
has $y = 0$ as horizontal asymptote, but the graph crosses the asymptote infinitely many times (at $x = n\pi$ for each integer $n$).

(It *is* true that the graph of a function cannot cross a *vertical* asymptote, but that's essentially a consequence of the vertical line test.)

Comment: The statement about vertical asymptotes presumes $f$ is _continuous_, of course....

Answer (score 4):

Here's a verbal picture of what's going on...

The horizontal asymptote of a rational function describes **end behavior**. That is, it describes how the output of your graph, $f(x)$, behaves as your input, $x$, gets really really big, as in far from zero (as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$). The graph itself can cross this asymptote.

This is a bit different than what a vertical asymptote describes. A vertical asymptote occurs at a **discontinuity**, where $x$ is not defined. That's why your graph can't cross the vertical asymptote. As your graph approaches the discontinuity, or the break in your graph, the function often explodes towards either $\pm \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

The graph of the function $y=\frac{x}{x^2+4}$ goes  through $(0,0)$,  but as $x$ goes to $\infty$ it flattens towards the point $(0,1)$.

Comment: The graph will not cross it. It will go up from zero but after a while, it slopes down continuously towards that asymptotes.

Comment: The person who asked the question had the misconception that a graph could not cross a horizontal asymptote.